# Difference between platformwebservices vs ycommercewebservices

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the ideal scenario to use platformwebservices and ycommercewebservices, and what is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Platformwebservices**

> provide secure CRUD access to all models in the service layer over a well understood and widely adopted protocol.

A secured RESTful access to all Hybris models, when you create or update an item the platform web services will generate / update the API for you.It's accessible from '/ws410'. You do not need to change anything within this extension.

**Ycommercewebservices**

> exposes part of the Commerce Facades as REST-based web services, including calls for product search and product details. The focus is to provide a working example of how a REST-based API can be exposed.

First it's a template, as it starts with 'Y' so to create your own you need to run 'ant extgen'. It will provide you RESTful access to few out of the box Facades. Up to you to add more Facades or update the existing one.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, but my question is more about-what is it that cannot be achieved through platformwebservices for which we need to generate commerceWebServices.

Comment: Your question is unclear platformwebservices is to generate a CRUD API for your data model. commerceWebServices is to expose your facades trough a RESTful API. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am new to hybris, basically I want to design solution for implementing OCC in my project, and I want to understand if I can use platformwebservices instead of commerceWebservices for that, and if not, why?

Comment: You can't because they are not meant to be used for the same purpose, read this : https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Omni+Commerce+Connect+Module

Comment: Hah none of you have even mentioned the new ywebservices based service extensions...

Answer (score 1):

for OCC implementations use `CommerceWebservices`. `PlatformWebservices` are for doing basic CRUD operations and it completely bypasses the business logic .

So if you want to leverage any hybris provided business logic and don't want to write your own logic for example cart management `CommerceWebservices` is the recommended way.